# Есть функция, которая кодирует мое сообщение, но нужно теперь раскодировать, придерживаясь стиля самого кода который кодирует

Tags: javascript

Есть функция, которая кодирует мое сообщение, но нужно теперь раскодировать, придерживаясь стиля самого кода который кодирует

```
let a = 'af' //получается '.4-2.6-1.4-1.20-16.1-2'
const encode = input => [...input]
    .map((x, i) => [x.charCodeAt(0), i])
    .sort()
    .flatMap(x => x)
    .join('.')
    .match(/./g)
    .flatMap((x, i) => new Array(x == '.' ? 1 : 2 + x * 2).fill((1 + i) % 2)) //тут была ошибка, исправил
    .join('')
    .replace(/(([01])\2*)/g, x => `${(+x ? '.' : '-')}${x.length}`)
```

Я что то начал, но боюсь иду не в том направлении((

```
const decode = input => input
    .replace(/[.-]/g, ',')
    .substring(1)
    .split(',')
    .map((x, i) => i%2 ? x = '0'.repeat(x) : '1'.repeat(x))
    .join('')
    .split('')

let q = '.4-2.6-1.4-1.20-16.1-2'
// теперь при раскожировании вводим то что получилось при кодировании и получаем 'af'
console.log(decode(q))
```

Comment: а раскодирование точно возможно во всех случаях?

Comment: ну типа если закодировать let a = 'af' , то получится .4-2.6-1.4-1.20-16.1-2, я вот не понял как ловить точку и запятую при разделении на массивы типа [ [ 97, 0 ], [ 102, 1 ] ], а дальше вроде уже проще, если собрать то дальше остаеться только отсортировать по второму элементу массива.

Comment: Добавь в вопрос словесное описание как ты хочешь раскодировать, судя по комментарию - ты что-то не то делаешь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для раскодирования достаточно выполнять шаги в обратную сторону.

1. конечная строка представляет собой список из символов `.` и `-`, которые представляют собой `1` и `0` соответственно и числом, указывающим их количество. Для их получения можно воспользоваться заменой с регулярным выражением

   ```
   .replace(/(\.|\-)(\d+)/g, (_, t, val) => t == '.' ? '1'.repeat(val) : '0'.repeat(val))
   ```

   определяем какой символ и вставляем нужное количество
2. собираем одинаковые символы в группы: если количество символов четное - это значимое число - если в группе одна цифра - это точка
3. объединяем все в одну строку - получаем промежуточное представление из чисел разделенных точками
4. два стоящих числа разделенных точкой - являются значением и индексом. Их можно получить с помощью регулярного выражения

   ```
   .match(/\d+\.\d+/g)
   ```
5. Получить отдельные значения для индекса

   ```
    .map(x => x.split('.'))
   ```
6. отсортировать по индексам
7. получить значение символа по коду

   ```
   .map(x => String.fromCharCode(x[0]))
   ```
8. вернуть получившуюся строку

```js
let a = 'af' //получается '.4-2.6-1.4-1.20-16.1-2'
const encode = input => [...input]
  .map((x, i) => [x.charCodeAt(0), i])
  .sort()
  .flatMap(x => x)
  .join('.')
  .match(/./g)
  .flatMap((x, i) => new Array(x == '.' ? 1 : 2 + x * 2).fill((1 + i) % 2)) //тут была ошибка, исправил
  .join('')
  .replace(/(([01])\2*)/g, x => `${(+x ? '.' : '-')}${x.length}`);

const encoded = encode(a)
console.log(encoded);

const decode = (input) => input
  .replace(/(\.|\-)(\d+)/g, (_, t, val) => t == '.' ? '1'.repeat(val) : '0'.repeat(val))
  .match(/([01])\1*/g)
  .map(x => x.length == 1 ? '.' : (x.length - 2) / 2)
  .join('')
  .match(/\d+\.\d+/g)
  .map(x => x.split('.'))
  .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
  .map(x => String.fromCharCode(x[0]))
  .join('');

const decoded = decode(encoded);

console.log(decoded, a == decoded);
```

Также можно отметить, что первый шаг и второй делают противоположные действия, следовательно шаг получения строки с единичками и ноликами можно пропустить. Так как достаточно только длины блоков - а она есть в конечной строке.

```js
let a = 'af' //получается '.4-2.6-1.4-1.20-16.1-2'
const encode = input => [...input]
  .map((x, i) => [x.charCodeAt(0), i])
  .sort()
  .flatMap(x => x)
  .join('.')
  .match(/./g)
  .flatMap((x, i) => new Array(x == '.' ? 1 : 2 + x * 2).fill((1 + i) % 2)) //тут была ошибка, исправил
  .join('')
  .replace(/(([01])\2*)/g, x => `${(+x ? '.' : '-')}${x.length}`);

const encoded = encode(a)
console.log(encoded);

const decode = (input) => input
  .replace(/(\.|\-)(\d+)/g, (_, __, val) => val == 1 ? '.' : (val - 2) / 2)
  .match(/\d+\.\d+/g)
  .map(x => x.split('.'))
  .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
  .map(x => String.fromCharCode(x[0]))
  .join('');

const decoded = decode(encoded);

console.log(decoded, a == decoded);
```

Comment: Супер)) Спасибо, завтра буду разбираться в коде))